# AspNetIdentity no longer working in MVC app after I had selected the tables in add ADO.NET Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My MVC web with User Logins was working just fine for weeks on end.

My MVC model classes did not contain any AspNetIdentity class components matching the Database ..
My MVC DBContext had no classes AspNetIdenty , user etc.
My DBContext OnModelCreation was empty..

```
public partial class MyDB : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyDB()
        : base("name=MyDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

        public static MyDB Create()
        {
            return new MyDB();
        }

}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I went to Add another table via ADO.NET Entity code first approach (making sure to uncheck add connection to web config) - I selected (because I was curious) the AspNetTables from the database.

They along with my table I wanted and a new context was added to my project.
I looked at files I was curious about. I deleted the AspNetIdentity entity Class files and I deleted the newly created context.

Now in the code below (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))

I get this complaint from my Web Application:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> MynameSpace.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   MynameSpace.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based
>   on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is
>   based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private void CreateRolesandUsers()
        {
            MyDB context = new myDB();  

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin")) // ERROR HERE
            {

                var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
   }
```

**

> What in the world is wrong?

**

I don't think I should be required to add classes for the tables and modelBuilder code - when the stupid thing was working before! Aaargh - I know MS stuck me with some OBSCURE Visual Studio code , tag or whatever generated by the ado.net code generator.

Just an FYI: I know what it means that I have no key. Remember this was working and now it is not. Same Context as before , same tables as before. 
So the question is not should I add the other things in my project - but how can I make it work like before - where I did not need those classes and OnModelCreating ..

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Did you try to delete the entire database and then generate the full db. from a code first approach? 2. I am not clear what part of you code is original (and working) and what code was added.

Comment: @CharlesdeM.  I did not delete the database - no reason to delete it. The only code I have added to the project is one of my project entity classes not related to any of the identity tables, and has no code in it for the AspNetIdentity entity - basically tblPart, Id, Name, virtual Icollection items , tblItems Id, Name..

Answer (score 0):

After a little head banging my dbcontext has the following line of code , I simply commented out the entire method ..

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {   

       // All that junk created in here commented out. Method left uncommented.

    }
```

COMMENT OUT THE BELOW METHOD:

```
    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{   



    //}
```

That will allow it to work! 
What a pile of garbage that is.. - the method override seems to run some kind of base code for OnModelCreating() if you have an override method with NOTHING NO CODE IN IT..! ..

Comment: That's a bit risky without knowing what that method does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if the model does not exist - the base model would create it from a migration , when you override you tell it how to create the models in the database - because you have code first model. If you are going to script the databases - that part is not important. As long as your code entity classes match. My database already exists - so I do not need anything to create it.